# Javascript comparison logic - let a = 1 . a === (3 || 1 ) false, why?

Tags: javascript, logic, comparison

I've tried to use this comparison statement and was almost sure that's gonna work, but it's not. Could you explain why ?

```
let a = 1 
a === ( 1 || 3 ) // true 
a === ( 3 || 1 ) // false
```

Thanks for responses :)

Comment: Have you  looked up what using the `||` operator resolves to? It might be informative.

Comment: See [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `OR` comparison if any one of the leftmost expression is true the entire expression results to true. Thus,

`( 1 || 3 )` will select `1` as `1` is a defined value on the leftmost side and when you do `a === ( 1 || 3 )` it will be `true` as `a === 1` is `true`, given that `a = 1`.

```js
let a = 1;
let rightCondition = ( 1 || 3 );
//this will give 1
console.log(rightCondition);
console.log(a === rightCondition);
```

But, `( 3 || 1 )` will select `3` as `3` is a defined value on the leftmost side and when you do `a === ( 3 || 1 )` it will be `false` as `a === 3` is `false`, given that `a = 1`.

```js
let a = 1;
let rightCondition = ( 3 || 1 );
//this will give 3
console.log(rightCondition);
console.log(a === rightCondition);
```

Comment: @mrCod3r you can tick mark the answer if it was useful for you. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the comparison you're looking for is actually:

```
let a = 1 
a === 1 || a === 3  // true
```

Comment: yes, at first I thought the result will be the same

Answer (score 1):

Integers like 1 and 3 (but not 0) are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript. So, the first of your comparisons returns 1 because 1 is truthy and the leftmost operand and the second one returns 3 because 3 is also truthy and the leftmost operand. The comparison stops immediately when a truthy value has been found (starting at the left). So, in your second comparison, the program does not even look at the 1.